# Split a string having colon and store in vector using regex pattern in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I want to split the string `"Input\temp.csv:1:14"` separated by colon and store the results in a vector. What should the regex look like? Or do I need an entirely different approach?

```
sInpFileName = "Input\temp.csv:1:14";

regex colon(?);
vector<string> MyVector(sregex_token_iterator(sInpFileName.begin(), sInpFileName.end(), colon, 1), sregex_token_iterator());
```

MyVector should have three element as

```
Input\temp.csv
1
14
```

Comment: I'm sure one can do this with a regex, but if using [`string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) with [`string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) seems more apt. It's also way easier.

Comment: Ehm, scratch that "if" above, that's a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

[[live]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4098c2b7f5d078ff)

```
std::string sInpFileName = "Input\\temp.csv:1:14";

std::regex re{"([^:]+)"};
std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> it{sInpFileName.begin(), sInpFileName.end(), re, 1};
decltype(it) end{};
while (it != end) std::cout << *it++ << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks Grorge. It works ... :)  What should be the change in regular expression if i want to skip first occurrence of : for eg- "C:\\test\\Input\\temp.csv:1:14" and similar output C:\\test\\Input\\temp.csv 1 14

Comment: @PravinHolkar try this one: `std::regex re{"([^:]+(:\\\\)?[^:]*)"};`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Boost variant.

```
static const boost::regex pat(":");
boost::sregex_token_iterator iter( sInpFileName.begin(), sInpFileName.end(), pat, -1);
boost::sregex_token_iterator end;
std::vector<std::string> MyVector(iter, end);
```